# How to Get JSONObject Only Android

Tags: android

```
{"StatusID":"1","Error":"Register Successfull."}
```

This my JSONObject I don't know how to convert it to string in android

Advice me Please

Thank.

Comment: this link may help you.. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the JSON object and get values like this.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
String statusId = jsonObject.getString("StatusID");
String error = jsonObject.getString("Error");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just convert this json:

```
{"StatusID":"1","Error":"Register Successfull."}
```

you must use toString() method.

If you want get "status id" or "error" you should use getString() method

See [THIS](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).